# valgrind not calling overloaded global operator new of application

Tags: c++, linux, valgrind

In the following short program: when run without valgrind the overloaded global new operator is called, with valgrind it is not called at all, instead it apparently calls the global new operator of valgrind. My question is: how can we get valgrind to call the global new/delete of the application? (valgrind 3.13.0; OS Linux, Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, x86_64) (The overloaded operator of the application can mark memory as used by using VALGRIND_MEMPOOL_ALLOC/VALGRIND_MEMPOOL_FREE macros, but we don't get there)
(Edit: with valgrind 3.10.1 the global new operator is called)

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <new>

void* operator new (size_t size_i) throw (std::bad_alloc)
{
        fprintf(stderr,"new %d (operator new (size_t size_i) throw (std::bad_alloc))\n", __LINE__);
        return malloc(size_i);
}

void* operator new (size_t size_i, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_value) throw()
{
        fprintf(stderr,"new %d (operator new (size_t size_i, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_value) throw())\n", __LINE__);
        return malloc(size_i);
}

void* operator new[] (size_t size_i) throw (std::bad_alloc)
{

        fprintf(stderr,"new %d (operator new[] (size_t size_i) throw (std::bad_alloc)) \n", __LINE__);
        return malloc(size_i);
}

void* operator new[] (size_t size_i, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_value) throw()
{
        fprintf(stderr,"new %d (operator new[] (size_t size_i, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_value) throw()) \n", __LINE__);
        return malloc(size_i);
}

void operator delete (void* p_i) throw()
{
        fprintf(stderr, "delete %d (operator delete (void* p_i) throw())\n",__LINE__);
        free(p_i);
}

void operator delete (void* p_i, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_constant) throw()
{
        fprintf(stderr, "delete %d\n",__LINE__);
        free(p_i);
}

void operator delete[] (void* p_i) throw()
{
        fprintf(stderr, "delete %d\n",__LINE__);
        free(p_i);
}

void operator delete[] (void* p_i, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_constant) throw()
{
        fprintf(stderr, "delete %d\n",__LINE__);
         free(p_i);
}

#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
        fprintf(stderr, "ku !\n");

        char * a = new char[123];
        delete [] a;

        int * b = new int();
        delete b;

        return 0;
}
```

Now compile it

```
gcc -g valg.cpp  -lstdc++
```

run it without valgrind

```
$ ./a.out
ku !
new 19 (operator new[] (size_t size_i) throw (std::bad_alloc))
delete 43
new 6 (operator new (size_t size_i) throw (std::bad_alloc))
delete 31 (operator delete (void* p_i) throw())
```

With valgrind global operator new is not called.

```
valgrind ./a.out
==24181== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==24181== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==24181== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==24181== Command: ./a.out
==24181==
ku !
==24181==
==24181== HEAP SUMMARY:
==24181==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24181==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 127 bytes allocated
==24181==
==24181== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==24181==
==24181== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==24181== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: That, of course, is how valgrind is supposed (1) to work, so I'm not entirely sure what you expected it to do... 
(1) I mean, if you actually understand how valgrind does leak detection, it takes over calls to various memory allocation functions (and their respective free functions). This includes, but is not limited to, `malloc`, `free`, `calloc`, `new`, `delete`. It implements its own version of these to track memory allocations.

Comment: No valgrind is not supposed to work this way; please look at http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.mempools there are special facilities to allow valgrind to track memory allocated by application specific allocators. The allocator is supposed to mark memory returned by it as allocated / free.

Comment: Also valgrind 3.10.1 does call the application specific allocator, but 3.13.3 doesn't.

Comment: I got a kind answer from the valgrind mailing list; it says that beginning with valgrind 3.12.0 one must add  --soname-synonyms=somalloc=nouserintercepts to the valgrind command line, in this case only malloc is intercepted by valgrind, and the application new/delete are not.